# I am getting a error "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

When I click of a Button I'm using the following code for a function for a Dialog:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/normalize.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

$(function() {
    $('.checked').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure?</p>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {alert('you chose yes');},
                "No":  function() {alert('you chose no');},
                "Cancel":  function() {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
      });
});

//]]>  

</script>
```

it is showing this error

```
TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function


"Cancel":  function() {
```

can anyone tell me why i am getting error,thanks.

Comment: It looks like jqueryUI is not included properly but I don't see why.. Are you perhaps calling the page with https?

Comment: I created a fiddle using the code you provided and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/9LJx6/ Can you post a link to the page?